# Indention/align each String row in JavaScript when exporting as a .txt file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular, TypeScript/JavaScript to test this.

I have formatted each row with a new line at the back of the code

`formattedStr += car.Name + ' | ' + car.Color + ' | ' + car.Brand + '\r\n'`

Then exported it with

```
const file = new Blob([formattedStr], { type: 'text/plain' });
saveAs(file, 'myfilename');
```

Looks like this in .txt file

```
Name ABC | Color A | Brand XYZ
Name ABCDEF | Color SDA | Brand ZXXYZ
Name ABCEA | Color ADS | Brand CVDRXYZ
```

Now, attempts to format each row to align, expecting something like

```
Name ABC    | Color A   | Brand XYZ
Name ABCDEF | Color SDA | Brand ZXXYZ
Name ABCEA  | Color ADS | Brand CVDRXYZ
```

Had some trouble in creating Dynamic Indentions based on the longest word in each column. Any suggestions?

I have tested with `\t` to create symbol for tab but it creates a fixed indent in every row which makes every row not aligned.

```
Name ABC  | Color A  | Brand XYZ
Name ABCDEF | Color SDA  | Brand ZXXYZ
Name ABCEA | Color ADS  | Brand CVDRXYZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can [bundle](https://webpack.js.org/), [install](https://www.npmjs.com/) or copy the [code](https://github.com/substack/text-table/blob/master/index.js) you can use the `text-table` npm package.

```
var table = require('text-table');
var t = table([
    [ 'Name ABC', 'Color A', 'Brand XYZ' ],
    [ 'Name ABCDEF', 'Color SDA', 'Brand ZXXYZ' ],
    [ 'Name ABCEA', 'Color ADS', 'Brand CVDRXYZ' ]
], { hsep :' | '});

console.log(t);
```

**Output:**

```
Name ABC    | Color A   | Brand XYZ
Name ABCDEF | Color SDA | Brand ZXXYZ
Name ABCEA  | Color ADS | Brand CVDRXYZ
```

Comment: It helps. Thanks!